# In Xcode SWIFT how can I position UIViews proportionally to screen size?

Tags: storyboard, autolayout

I'd like to use storyboard's autosize, position, align etc to do the following.  I'd like to make a window that looks like the picture.

[image]

Everything stays centered and squared and aligned as depicted.

As the screen gets smaller I'd like the space between the views themselves and the margin between the views and the edge of the display to retract.  Basically the views stay the same size, but there's just less empty space around them and between them.  They just crowd in as the screen gets smaller.  Vice versa as the screen gets larger.

Bonus: possibly if the views were ever too close and almost touching each other, then the views themselves would begin to shrink in order not to touch each other.

All that pinning is fixed, as far as I can see.  There doesn't seem to be a "please leave 1/12 of the screen size margin", "please have 1/6 of the screen size between these 2 buttons".

In the past I've done this programmatically, but the idea is to use the Xcode features to increase productivity.  Here's exactly what I'd want in pseudo code:

Along the horizontal axis:

If (screen width > 406)

Left text field width is 200

Right text field width is 200

Left margin is (screen width - 400) / 3

Space between text fields is (screen width - 400) / 3

Right margin is (screen width - 400) / 3

Else

Left text field width is (screen width - 6) /2

Right text field width is (screen width - 6) /2

Left margin = 2

Space between text fields = 2

Right margin = 2

End If

Answer (score 0):

All you need to achieve what you are looking for is understanding how [NSLayoutConstrains](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html) works and just put them on views by using storyboard without writing single line of code. For example lets take Text Box 1 and further examine this case.

Firstly from screenshot and your description I see that this box has preferred left margin, preferred width, and constant height. So the first constrains you are going to add are: leading space to superview with constant value of your choice,constant preferred width and constant height. Since the first and second constrains are only preferred their priority should be less than required (1000), lets say for example 750.

Next you will need to define that shrinking rule of left margin and that is done by adding another leading space constrain to superview but this time with constant of your minimum margin size, with relation greater than or equals and of course required priority.

Finally you should tell your box to never exceed superview's X center by adding trailing space to Superview.Center X constrain with constant of your minimum space between two boxes / 2, with relation grater than or equals and required priority

And thats all for the box 1, box 2 should have same constrains as box 1 but with reversed leading and trailing constrains, and so on...

Comment: That didn't do exactly what I wanted.  Now I've clarified the question a little

Answer (score -1):

You should use autolayout and set some constraints to each view.
This video makes things clear:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk&list=PL03RXnsvCFstArb6HZo9BhFKs9B3wKZer&index=9